# Visual basic base64 decoding not correctly decode

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
    Dim base64encoded As String = separatedText
    Dim base64decoded As String
    Dim data() As Byte
    data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded)
    base64decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data)
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", base64decoded, True)
```

Selected symbols is russian symbols
Must decode and save like this
[image]

But on out have like this

[image]

Comment: What is `separatedText` to start with? Is it *actually* base64 text? Please show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. We have no idea how the screenshots relate to the original data, but it's entirely possible that it wasn't really text...

Comment: You cannot store binary data in a string.  It will be destroyed when the string is normalized.  And decent odds the program will bomb when the data happens to match a surrogate.  You must use FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(data) instead.

Comment: thx guys, i solved the problem by solution of  Hans Passant)